# pyodbc is very slow on my machine but not on other machines

Tags: python, windows, odbc, db2, pyodbc

I am accessing a db2 (9.7) server running on the same network as my computer using python 2.7 and pyodbc 3.0.6.

The following is a very stripped down example of something similar to what i am trying to do.

```
import pyodbc as db

def dbcur(connectname):
    con = db.connect(connectname)
    cur = con.cursor()
    return cur,con


def main():

    print 'a'
    cur,con = dbcur('DSN=MYODBCCON')
    print 'b'


    # X.name is a short varchar
    qry = """
        select
        X.name as N
        from schema.table as X
        """

    print 'c'

    cur.execute(qry)

    print 'd'

    c = 0
    for row in cur:
        c+=1
        if not c%100:
            print c, row

    return

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

This code runs very slow on my windows 8 computer (100 rows in 10 seconds). However, on my colleagues computer with windows 7 this is lightning fast. His computer is simmilarly specced to mine, and he has the same versions of pyodbc and python, so i do not belive this to be an issue.

The problem persists when i use both IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER and IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER FOR ODBC.

Any suggsetions as to why this is so slow?

I am aware of things such as cur.fetchmany(), but i still expect this code to be much faster without using this.

**UPDATE**:

It turns out that ODBC was slow because tracing was turned on. I disabled tracing and the performance was back to what I expected it to be. (Tracing can be found under ODBC Data Sources in Windows 7 and 8.)

Comment: I would first check if this is a pyodbc/python issue or a general ODBC/configuration/... issue. Try a query using another ODBC client, for instance Excel. Is the performance slow using Excel?

Comment: It seems you are on to something. I tried the two ODBC connections in RazorSQL and the performance is slow here as well. Most notabaly: Task manager reports 100 % disk usage while loading rows. However, the write speed is low (~600 KB/s) and the read speed is near 0. I see almost no netwwork activity.

Comment: Most likely a Windows 8/DB2/ODBC driver issue, then.

Comment: It turns out ODBC tracing was on. I just switched it off and now it runs as fast as I expected. Doh.

Comment: ^ Please update your question to include your discovery. People would search the internet for similar problems; it would be easier if the question they find has an answer, too.

Comment: I got distracted at work. I've added the solution now.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the trace insight! I was pulling my hair out. Would it be appropriate to answer your own question below, rather than your comment?

Comment: Is there a way to turn tracing off via Python? I'm running Python on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that ODBC was slow because tracing was turned on. I disabled tracing and the performance was back to what I expected it to be. (Tracing can be found under ODBC Data Sources in Windows 7 and 8.)